# Path or pattern "bower_components/moment/moment.js" did not match any files

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've updated my project to ember-cli 0.1.3 (from 0.1.2) following [these](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.3) instructions. As soon as the process is completed i do
`ember serve` and I get the following error:

`Path or pattern "bower_components/moment/moment.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "bower_components/moment/moment.js" did not match any files
    at Object.multiGlob (/Users/riccardo/Dropbox/Workspace/caffeconcarla-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:202:13)
    at /Users/riccardo/Dropbox/Workspace/caffeconcarla-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/index.js:62:32
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/riccardo/Dropbox/Workspace/caffeconcarla-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:470:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/riccardo/Dropbox/Workspace/caffeconcarla-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:482:17)
    at $$$internal$$publish (/Users/riccardo/Dropbox/Workspace/caffeconcarla-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:453:11)
    at $$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/riccardo/Dropbox/Workspace/caffeconcarla-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1531:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)`

Has anyone been having the same issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following steps from the the root of your application,

- Make sure the bower_components directory exists,

  ```
  ls bower_components/
  ```
- Make sure .bowerrc has a directory entry for "bower_components" and not "vendor",

  ```
  cat .bowerrc
  ```

  This should return,

  ```
  {
    "directory": "bower_components"
  }
  ```
- Make sure momentjs is installed via bower,

  ```
  bower install --save momentjs
  ```
- Make sure the bower cache is clean

  ```
  bower cache clean
  ```
- Have bower install everything

  ```
  bower install
  ```
- Run ember

  ```
  ember serve
  ```